# Ошибка в обработке исключений в python

Tags: expect, try

Всем привет, у меня небольшая ошибка в обработке исключений. Я написал код и я не пойму в чем проблема: Я ввожу все данные, но у меня зависает цикл, ни ошибки, ни решения, ничего. На python я пишу недавно. Кому не трудно, то пожалуйста объясните почему не работало, Спасибо.
Сlear не ошибка я создал новый метод очистки консоли.

````
clear = lambda: os.system("cls")
vibor = 'y'
def prc():
    global vibor
    clear()
    print("\tПоиск процента")
    print("-------------------------------")
    procent_number = input("Введите число >>>")
    procent = input("Введите количество процентов >>>")
    while type(procent_number) != int(procent_number):
        try:
            procent_number = int(procent_number)
            procent = int(procent)
       
        except ValueError:
            print("Неверно введено число!")  
            sleep(0.8)
            clear()
            procent_number = input("Введите число >>>")
            print()
            procent = input("Введите количество процентов >>>")
            print()
    while type(procent_number) != float(procent):
        try:
            procent_number = float(procent_number)
            procent = float(procent)
        
        except ValueError:
            print("Неверно введено число!")  
            sleep(0.8)
            clear()
            procent_number = input("Введите число >>>")
            print()
            procent = input("Введите количество процентов >>>")
            print()
        result_procent = procent_number / 100 * procent
        print("Процент = "+float(result_procent))
        print(input("Хотите ли вы продолжить использование, Y - да или Нажмите любую кнопку >>>"))
        if vibor == 'y':
            clear()
            return prc()
        else:
            clear()
            return OSmenu()```

Спасибо за помощь)
````

Comment: `type() != int()` - не смущает сравнение класса с числом?

Comment: @slippyk Спасибо что помог с ошибкой